java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser$Feature from Module com.amazonaws:main from local module loader
I am working on an enhancement of an existing application, which is developed on EJB, Message Driven Bean, Hibernate, Maven as a build tool and wildfly 10 as a server. Enhancement is accessing the S3 bucket and placing zip file there, from this existing application. So, I have added the aws and opencsv dependency in pom.xml file.
There is MANIFEST.MF file where I have added the dependency for amazon aws and opencsv like below
Manifest-Version: SR.170.03
Class-Path: 
Dependencies: com.amazonaws,org.hibernate,com.opencsv

I am able to build the application successfully with maven clean install.
Then I place my war file in deployment folder of wildfly 10. Deployment of war is also successful.
When I execute the application in debug mode I get the below exception.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser$Feature from Module com.amazonaws:main from local module loader @80169cf (finder: local module finder @5427c60c (roots: D:\Installables\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,D:\Installables\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature

I have placed the amazonaws jar, fasterxml jar, and opencsv in wildfly 10 module folder like below




below is module.xml for amazonaws fasterxml and pom.xml
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.amazonaws">
     <resources>
         <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.125.jar"/> 
         <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.125.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-kms-1.12.125.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="jmespath-java-1.12.125.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
         <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
         <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-cbor"/>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
         <module name="org.joda.time"/>
         <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>
         <module name="software.amazon.ion"/>
     </dependencies>
 </module>

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core">
      <resources>
         <resource-root path="jackson-core-2.12.3.jar"/>
     </resources>

     <dependencies>
         <module name="javax.api"/>
     </dependencies>
 </module>

 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>uk.co.tui</groupId>
     <artifactId>Cyrus</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>
     <name>Cyrus8</name>
     <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
     <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>Central Maven repository</id>
           <name>Jboss Loggings</name>
           <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
         <repository>
           <id>Central JBOSS Maven repository</id>
           <name>Jboss Maven Logging</name>
           <url>https://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
         <sonar.binaries>target/classes</sonar.binaries>
         <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
         <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
         <sonar.junit.reportsPaths>target/test-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPaths>
         <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
         <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
         <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
         <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
         <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
             src/main/java/**/entity/BookParametersPK.java,
         </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
         <sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero>true</sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero>
     </properties>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
             <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.2</version>
         </dependency>   
         <dependency>
             <groupId>asm</groupId>
             <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
             <version>3.3.1</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>cglib</groupId>
             <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
             <version>2.2.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>4.10</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
             <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
             <version>1.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
             <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
             <type>pom</type>
             <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
             <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
             <version>1.9.5</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
             <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
             <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
             <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
             <version>3.2</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>jboss</groupId>
             <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
             <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
             <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb3</artifactId>
             <version>7.1.0.CR1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
             <artifactId>wildfly-ejb3</artifactId>
             <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
             <artifactId>wildfly-naming</artifactId>
             <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>jboss</groupId>
             <artifactId>jboss-jmx</artifactId>
             <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
             <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
         </dependency>             
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
             <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
             <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
             <version>1.12.125</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
             <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
             <version>4.0</version>
         </dependency>       
     </dependencies>
     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.6.1</version> <!-- Replace with the desired version -->
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.6</source> <!-- Replace with the desired Java version -->
                     <target>1.6</target> <!-- Replace with the desired Java version -->
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                     <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                     <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                     <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                     <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                     <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                     <argLine>${surefire.jacoco.argLine}</argLine>
                     <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run -->
                     <excludes>
                         <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                     </excludes>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                 <!-- Unit testing configuration -->
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                         <configuration>
                             <propertyName>surefire.jacoco.argLine</propertyName>
                             <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                         </configuration>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                         </goals>
                     </execution>
                     <execution>
                         <id>jacoco-report</id>
                         <phase>test</phase>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>report</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                             <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                             <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                             <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>

                 </executions>
                 <configuration>
                     <propertyName>surefire.jacoco.argLine</propertyName>
                     <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.3.2</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <finalName>abcdef8</finalName>  
                     <archive>
                         <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                     </archive>                  
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>

         </plugins>
     </build>
 </project>



I have already gone through topic related to such error but didn't get solution. Someboy please help on this
I have tried placing all the amazonaws jar in one place in the wildfly 10 module.
